# Existe alguna alternativa a <audio AUTOPLAY> en Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html

Lo que quiero hacer es que apenas ingrese a mi pagina web suene una canción de fondo, pero el autoplay no funciona, según tengo entendido este fue anulado por los navegadores porque las paginas abusaban de el con el spam.

Comment: Chrome deshabilito la función autoplay...

Comment: Y hay alguna alternativa?

Answer (score 1):

Aún funciona el autoplay en los navegadores, pero otra forma de iniciar la reproducción apenas termine de cargar la página es con Javascript:

```
<audio src="audio.mp3" id="audio"></audio>

<script>
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
      document.getElementById('audio').play();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: Nose porque pero no me tira ningún error ni nada pero tampoco funciona, muchas gracias igualmente por tomarte el tiempo.